# Как примонтировать папку в Docker?

Tags: docker

имеется файл docker-compose

```
version: "3"
services:
  pas:
    build: docker_pas
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - ./mount/pas/:/pas/workdir/
    links:
      - db     
  db:
    build: docker_db
    tty: true
    #volumes:
    #  - ./mount/db/:db/workdir/
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
```

и два dockerfile. один для базы и второй для Python.

python

```
FROM python:3.7-slim
LABEL maintainer="1"
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade && apt-get install nano cron -y

COPY /requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
WORKDIR /workdir/
COPY /workdir/ ./
COPY /workdir/parser/cronrun.sh /etc/cron.d/cronrun.sh
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/cronrun.sh
RUN service cron start
```

База данных

```
FROM postgres
LABEL maintainer="1"
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade && apt-get install nano -y
FROM library/postgres
COPY init.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
WORKDIR /workdir/
ADD  /workdir /workdir/
```

Контейнеры собираются и все что указано в dockerfiles переносится в контейнер, но инструкция

volumes:
  - ./mount/pas/:/pas/workdir/

не отрабатывается.
если указать как сейчас ничего не монтируется.

если указать так. как собственно и называется папка в контейнере, то вообще ничего никуда не копируется. хотя докер успешно запускается.

volumes:
  - ./mount/pas/:/workdir/

Как правильнее сделать чтобы собрать два связанных контейнера и вывести их содержимое на хост.
 ОС - windows 10.

Comment: а вы добавляли shared drives в настройках Docker for Windows?

Comment: да, это стоит. папка на хосте создается если ее нет. в нее ничего не монтируется.